# Is the initialised Firebase app not the same as the import "firebase"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, config, firebaseui

I wrote a react app and wanted to use firebase (npm firebase) for Authentication...

first, I initialise the firebase app:

```
import React from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import 'firebase/auth'

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_databaseURL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId,
}

export const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

let FirebaseContext = React.createContext(app)

export default FirebaseContext
```

then I import the context in App.js and provide the configured firebase app to it:

```
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import ListPokemonsRebassJS from './components/ListPokemonsRebassJS'
import Header from './components/Header'
import FinForm from './components/FinForm'
import StockComponent from './components/StockComponent'
import Login from './components/Login'
// import { AuthProvider } from './components/Auth'
import FirebaseContext from './firebase'
import { app } from './firebase'
function App() {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <FirebaseContext.Provider value={app}> <<<<<-----HERE!
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' exact component={Header}></Route>
                        <Route
                            path='/pokemons'
                            component={ListPokemonsRebassJS}
                        ></Route>
                        <Route path='/login' component={Login}></Route>
                        <Route path='/form' exact component={FinForm}></Route>
                        <Route path='/form/:wkn' component={StockComponent} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </FirebaseContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Then in the Login component, I try to show the firebaseui login together with my login handling logic:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import FirebaseContext from '../firebase'
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'
import firebase from 'firebase'

function Login() {
    const fb = useContext(FirebaseContext)
    console.log({ fb })
    console.log({ firebase })
    useEffect(() => {
        fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log({ user })
                // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
                // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
                const uid = user.uid
                // ...
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                // ...
            }
        })
        var ui =
            firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() ||
            new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())

        ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
            signInOptions: [
                firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                {
                    emailLinkSignIn: function () {
                        return false
                    },
                },
            ],
            // Other config options...
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div id='firebaseui-auth-container'></div>
        // <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
        //  {(firebase) => {
        //      console.log(firebase)
        //  }}
        // </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Now the problem (or weird behaviour) that I got is that somehow, the configured firebase app exported from './firebase.js' (that I import into Login.js) seems not to be the same as the simple import 'firebase' (that I also import in Login.js component) ...

the "firebase" object has auth, app and initializeApp and other properties on it, while my instance of firebase is of type "FirebaseappImpl" and has not such properties like "auth" on it. Why??

This was totally confusing, because I got the error `Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined` because auth didn't simply exist on my firebase instance ??
do I need to import firebase everytime in my files for all the firebase functions then?
And what is my firebase instance specifically for then?